# Strange results generated for ORACLE sql query

Tags: oracle, datetime, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

I am having some problem with weblogic ACTIVE table in a Oracle database (Oracle version 11g)
During the investigation of that problem, I tried to get the result of following query.

Expected result of following query is, to get a value with current time + 30 seconds as the second field "**to_char(sysdate + (30/86400), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')**". 
But sometimes I get the result otherway (first field is greater than second field by 30 second). After few executions, I get the results correct way again. and after sometime, I get the incorrect result.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'), to_char(sysdate + (30/86400), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss') from dual;
```

Could any one help me to understand what is the problem here? Is this a bug in Oracle DB?

[image: The incorrect result]

**The incorrect result:**

```
to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')     to_char(sysdate + (30/86400), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')  
2013-07-05 10:07:54                     2013-07-05 10:07:24
```

2013-07-05 10:07:**54**                     2013-07-05 10:07:**24**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format string should be `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'`. Your code displays the month, not the minute.